# Adding 1 to Value in Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key, updates, key-value

I have seen others ways of adding 1 to a value in a dictionary. 
I simply keep getting an error when I try to add a value of 1 to a dictionary key value in python.

Here is my code:

```
arr = {('1', '20'): [0], ('15', '14'): [0]}
```

I want to add 1 to key ('1', '20').

Here is my code:

```
w = 1
x = 20
arr[(w, x)] += 1
```

I get the error code:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I simply do not know what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Two issues:

1. The keys of your dictionary are tuples of strings, but you're trying to index into the dictionary using a tuple of ints.
2. The values in your dictionary are (1-length) lists of ints, but you're trying to add a number to one of those lists.

You might want something like this:

```
w = '1'
x = '20'
arr[(w, x)][0] += 1
```

Without seeing more of your code, it could be that you want something more like this:

```
# dictionary mapping tuples of ints to ints
arr = { (1, 20): 0, (15, 14): 0 }

# now we can just use ints    
w = 1
x = 20
# and no need to use [0] to get the first element of the list
# (because it's no longer a list)
arr[(w, x)] += 1
```